# Is the Cycler Rifle affected by gravity?

Tags: star-wars-battlefront

The cycler rifle is the only gun that shoots a non grenade solid projectile. I was wondering if for the really long range shots if it is affected by gravity at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes

As mentioned in the battlefront wiki:

> **The Cycler Rifle functions as a long range sniper rifle similar to the Pulse Cannon**, the comparison between the two is usually in-favor of the Pulse Cannon. Since the Pulse Cannon can one shot kill at full charge and a headshot regardless of the amount of charge and since its unlocked a lot earlier then it, its cooldown is also at first in favor of the Cycler Rifle, but once upgraded, the Pulse Cannon can be fired more often (7 vs 10 secs). The **Pulse also has** less time to travel and **less bullet drop compared to the Cycler**.

Emphasis by me

Also, there are many threads discussing what a significant bullet drop was added in comparison to Beta:

> Man i've been rushing the levels to get the **cycler rifle and they added a huge bullet drop nerf compared** to the one in the beta.

Source [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/StarWarsBattlefront/comments/3tcw65/cycler_rifle_has_been_badly_nerfed_its_a_trap/).

About the cycle rifle:

> The Bad:
>
> **Extreme bullet drop: both in terms of distance before bullet drop
>   starts, and amount of bullet drop once it's in effect.**
>
> No scope reticles to help compensate for bullet drop. Scope only has
>   basic crosshairs.
>       Very slow projectile speed
>
> Expensive and late-stage unlock (currently the penultimate unlock of all cards)
>
> Any hit that's not a headshot does less than 100% damage

Source [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/StarWarsBattlefront/comments/3u7u95/cycler_rifle_badly_needs_some_unnerfing/).

Emphasis by me

Comment: well so far you're getting the bounty, but I'm going to wait a little longer to see if anyone gives another answer.